# JavaFX Dynamic Edit View of DAO

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to design my application UI as dynamically as possible so whenever a new DAO is created there should not much Code needed to display the DAO on UI.
So far I have created an Annotation for displaying the DAO in a TableView. That works very well.

Now I want to create a Dynamic View for Editing/Creating a new Instance of the DAO. My plan is that I only need to create an FXML while the Components value inside get filled automatically with the properties inside the DAO.

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Here is an example:

**Country**

```
public class Country extends DatabaseItem
{
    private String name;
    private String shortage;
    private String flagPath;

    private ImageView flag = null;

    public Country()
    {

    }
    [.. Getters/Setters ..]
}
```

**Goal**

[image]

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane fx:id="bPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="177.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <GridPane fx:id="gPane" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="294.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="450.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="450.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblCountryName" text="Ländername:" />
            <Label fx:id="lblCountryShortage" text="Abkürzung:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="lblCountryFlag" text="Flaggen-Symbol:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtCountryName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtCountryShortage" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <BorderPane fx:id="bPaneFlag" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <center>
                  <TextField fx:id="txtCountryFlag" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <BorderPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="5.0" />
                     </BorderPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
               </center>
               <right>
                  <Button fx:id="btnCountryFlag" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnCountryFlagClicked" text="..." BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
               </right>
               <left>
                  <ImageView fx:id="imgViewCountryFlag" fitHeight="48.0" fitWidth="90.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <BorderPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="5.0" />
                     </BorderPane.margin>
                  </ImageView>
               </left>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </BorderPane>
            <ButtonBar fx:id="btnBar" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
              <buttons>
                <Button fx:id="btnAbort" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAbortClicked" text="Abbrechen" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnSave" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnSaveClicked" text="Speichern" />
              </buttons>
            </ButtonBar>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: You may have a look into JavaFX FXML [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding).

Comment: You are not clear what you want. Do you want to create a new type of object(DAO) using FXML UI or you want to create a new instance of the object showed above using the FXML?

Comment: please post the comple `fxml`

Comment: @IldiX I want to create a new Instance when I click on button "new" and edit a given instance if I click on button "edit".

Comment: @c0der That's the complete FXML.

Comment: With no imports ?

Comment: @c0der You're right. I've added them

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a controller that accepts an instance of `Countrey` (model), to your `fxml`. A very simplistic version of it can look like:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    TextField txtCountryName, txtCountryShortage, txtCountryFlag;

    public void setModel (final Country countrey){
        txtCountryName.setText(countrey.getName());
        txtCountryShortage.setText(countrey.getID());
        txtCountryFlag.setText(countrey.getFlagPath());
    }
}
```

And set the model when initializing :

```
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
      Parent root  =  loader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml").openStream());
      Controller controller = (Controller)loader.getController();
      controller.setModel(new Country("Germany","DE","https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/world-flags-square-vol-2/48/Germany-512.png"));
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm searching for since I need to specifiy a Controller for every Model. and need to hardcode the bindings. I want to have one method thats getting invoked and the UI builds depending on the given Model.

Comment: Both issues depend in what is the commonality  between the different `DAO`s (`DataSetItem` is not posted) and what are the differences.